# Get Two List from single list based on partial match

Tags: c#, list

I have got a List of string like this.

```
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_0
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_1
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_2
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_3
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_4
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_5
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_1
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_2
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_3
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_4
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_5
```

I want  two separate List from this list based on Distinct "MainItem.Item".
So answer will be

```
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_0
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_1
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_2
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_3
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_4
MainItem.Item1.AssetID_5
```

and

```
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_1
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_2
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_3
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_4
MainItem.Item2.AssetID_5
```

This is what I have tried so far. but it is not returning the desired output

```
var resultsLists = mainList.Select(GetPathFromKey).Distinct();

public static string[] Splitkey(string keyFromReading)
{
      return keyFromReading.Split('.');
}

public static string GetPathFromKey(string keyFromReading)
{
   string[] splittedStrings = Splitkey(keyFromReading);
   return String.Join(".", splittedStrings[0], splittedStrings[1]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? This looks like a job for regex - do you know anything about it?

Comment: I have updated my question & added tried code

Comment: You might also want to place the output you're getting at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use....

```
List<List<string>> allLists  = strings
    .Select(str => new { str, token=str.Split('.') })
    .Where(x => x.token.Length >= 2)
    .GroupBy(x => string.Concat(x.token.Take(2)))
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

This list contains two `List<string>`.The first contains 6 lines with Item1 and the second contains 5 lines with Item2.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Your code is doing exactly doing I wanted.